# Understanding polynomial division results

Tags: division, crc, polynomial-math, polynomials

I am trying to understand (and implement functions for) polynomial division.

My first step was to understand and compare the results of two online tools. The [first](http://www.ee.unb.ca/cgi-bin/tervo/calc.pl?num=0100000101000001&den=11111&f=d&e=1&p=1) is a formal GF(2) polynomial calculator. The [second](http://www.zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html) is a CRC polynomial calculator. I expected the remainder of the formal calculator being equal to the checksum of CRC calculator.

So I entered the following data to the formal calculator:

```
A = 0100000101000001 (should be same as "AA" ASCII data)
B = 11111
```

And I entered the following to the CRC calculator:

```
CRC order = 4
CRC polynom = F
Data sequence = AA
Initial = 0, Direct, no reverse input, no reverse output
```

I used width `4` and polynomial `F` (instead of `5` and `1F`) since the CRC calculator expects polynomials in standard notation that omit the leading 1-bit.

The CRC calulcator says checksum is `2` while formal calculator says binary remainder is `100` = `4`.

Why don't I get same results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add four zero bits to the dividend, i.e. `01000001010000010000`. Then you will get the same result.

See [Ross William's CRC tutorial](http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt) for how CRCs are calculated.

Comment: You are totally right. I tried that before and it didn't work. Probably I made some mistake without noticing it.